# SQLite3 near syntax error

Tags: python, sqlite, syntax

Trying to insert four different things into my database but I get following error:

```
near ".10586": syntax error
```

Here is my code:

```
b.execute("INSERT INTO logs VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)" % (hostname, os, ip.decode('utf-8'), time.strftime("%x")))
```

Comment: You don't need to change title with `[SOLVED]`. [Accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) the answer that solved your problem would mean the same thing. Also that will give you and answerer some reputation points.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are constructing the query using *string formatting*, you need quotes around the placeholders - `"%s"` instead of `%s`.

Instead, **make a parameterized query** and pass the query parameters in a second argument to `execute()` - this way you would let the database driver worry about the type conversion and you would prevent [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). The change is as simple as:

```
b.execute("INSERT INTO logs VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)", 
          (hostname, os, ip.decode('utf-8'), time.strftime("%x")))
```

Comment: Thank you, I figured this out right before you posted and facepalmed myself haha. What did you change in the second code snippet though?

Comment: Sqlite3 uses `?`as placeholder, not `%s`.